# I can't install packages on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt

I tried to install packages on the terminal but every time i try it shows this status!!
Example i tried to install php-5 and this what it says

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-cli
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commands in a terminal,

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install php5-cli
```